# OpenGL texture won't draw

Tags: opengl, c++

I'm sorry for asking such a common question, yet all of the other answers have not been very applicable to my problem. In short, I have begun learning OpenGL, and have started trying to draw the mandelbrot set as a small exercise. All of the pixel data is stored in a vector (I checked with GDB), yet for some reason when I transfer it into a texture and then draw it it does not work. To draw the texture I created a class called DrawBuffer, which handles all the OpenGL.

Any insight onto why this may be happening would be appreciated.

## Fragment Shader

```
#version 150

in vec2 Tex_coord;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main() {
    outColor = texture(tex, Tex_coord);
}
```

## Vertex Shader

```
#version 150

in vec2 position;
in vec2 tex_coord;

out vec2 Tex_coord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    Tex_coord = tex_coord;
}
```

## DrawBuffer.cpp

```
#include "Draw_Buffer.h"
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

// Util function to compile a shader from source
void compile_shader(GLuint &shader, const std::string &src) {
    std::ifstream is(src);
    std::string code;

    std::string temp_str;
    while (std::getline(is, temp_str)) {
        code += temp_str + '\n';
    }

    const char *c_code = code.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &c_code, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader);
}

Draw_Buffer::Draw_Buffer(Window<int> *win, const std::string &vertex_shader_src, const std::string &frag_shader_src) :
        window(win), buffer(std::vector<RGB>(window->size())), pos_iter(buffer.begin()) {
// Initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("error: GLFW unable to initialise");
    }

// Set up the window
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    screen.reset(glfwCreateWindow(win->width(), win->height(), "Mandelbrot Fractal", nullptr, nullptr));

    make_current();

// Initialise glew
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum glewinit = glewInit();

    if (glewinit != GLEW_OK) {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << "error: Glew unable to initialise" << glewinit;
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }

// Clear
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Generate shaders
    GLuint vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint frag_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    GLint compile_status;
    compile_shader(vertex_shader, vertex_shader_src);
    glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_status);
    if (compile_status != GL_TRUE) {
        char buffer[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader, 512, NULL, buffer);
        throw std::runtime_error(buffer);
    }

    compile_shader(frag_shader, frag_shader_src);
    glGetShaderiv(frag_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_status);
    if (compile_status != GL_TRUE) {
        char buffer[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(frag_shader, 512, NULL, buffer);
        throw std::runtime_error(buffer);
    }

// Put shaders into shader program
    shader_prog = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader_prog, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(shader_prog, frag_shader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shader_prog, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shader_prog);
    glUseProgram(shader_prog);

// Set shader attributes
    GLint pos_attrib = glGetAttribLocation(shader_prog, "position");
    glVertexAttribPointer(pos_attrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_attrib);

    GLint tex_coord_attrib = glGetAttribLocation(shader_prog, "tex_coord");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(tex_coord_attrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(tex_coord_attrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                        4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

// Generate texture
    glGenTextures(1, &mandelbrot_tex);
}

Draw_Buffer::~Draw_Buffer() {


// Terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();
}

void Draw_Buffer::flush() {

// Render pixels to image
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mandelbrot_tex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, window->width(), window->height(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, &buffer[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// Draw a rectangle
    const static GLfloat vertices[] = {
            // Position   Tex-coords
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
             1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
             1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
    };

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    const static GLuint elements[] = {
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0
    };

    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(screen.get());
}

void Draw_Buffer::keep_window_open() {
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(screen.get())) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

Draw_Buffer &operator<<(Draw_Buffer &db, const RGB &pixel) {
    if (db.pos_iter != db.buffer.end()) {
        *(db.pos_iter) = pixel;
        ++db.pos_iter;
        return db;
    }
    else {
        throw std::runtime_error("error: Cannot append past end of buffer : Remember to flush the buffer");
        return db;
    }
}
```

## DrawBuffer.h

```
#include "Window.h"
#include "Cleanup.h"

struct RGB {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};

class Draw_Buffer {
friend Draw_Buffer &operator<<(Draw_Buffer &db, const RGB &pixel);
    std::unique_ptr<Window<int>> window;

    std::unique_ptr<GLFWwindow, Cleaner> screen;

    std::vector<RGB> buffer;

    // Tracks position of appending in buffer
    std::vector<RGB>::iterator pos_iter;

    // Texture where pixels are written to
    GLuint mandelbrot_tex;

    // GLSL Shader program
    GLuint shader_prog;
public:
    Draw_Buffer(Window<int> *, const std::string &, const std::string &);
    ~Draw_Buffer();

    void make_current() {
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(screen.get());
    }

    void flush();

    void keep_window_open();
};

Draw_Buffer &operator<<(Draw_Buffer &db, const RGB &pixel);


#endif //MANDELBROT_FRACTAL_DRAWER_DRAW_BUFFER_H
```

Comment: I don't see where you're setting the uniform that specifies the texture unit you're going to use. I'd think you'd want to call `glUniform1i()` at some point, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's a typo. You're making 2 vertex shaders.

```
GLuint vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint frag_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); // Should be GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER
```

Also from the code you have supplied, it seems like you're not creating a vertex array. So prior to `glGenBuffers(1, &vbo)` add:

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

Note that the above vertex array must be bound before calling `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` and `glVertexAttribPointer()`.

Also given that `glDrawElements()` and `glfwSwapBuffers()` is in `Draw_Buffer::flush()`. I'm assuming this method is called to draw the rectangle. The extremely bad thing about this is that you're calling `glGenBuffers()`, etc. each frame. But you're never calling `glDeleteBuffers()`. The best thing would be to move all that into `Draw_Buffer::Draw_Buffer()`.

Then inside `Draw_Buffer::flush()` simply have:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glfwSwapBuffers(screen.get());
```

Also your driver is most likely clever enough to catch this. But as mentioned in the comments, you need to do this as well:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog, "tex"), 0);
```

Last but not least, since your geometry is static you can replace `GL_STREAM_DRAW` with `GL_STATIC_DRAW`.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer :)
I really appreciate it when people put time into their answers and I hope, when I become more experienced I can eventually do the same.

Comment: You're welcome! This is why I mainly enjoy answering OpenGL questions (on Stack Overflow). Because there you usually have time to think, instead of having to answer within 10 seconds if it was a regular Java or Python question. Besides that, just keep on learning, it will get easier, and one day you'll be able to help others as well! :)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you yet for some reason I am still not getting anything drawing. Even when I try to test that the texture is even working by changing the outColor from the frag shader to `vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` I am still getting a black screen :(

Comment: You probably accidentally missed something. I did indeed test it, [so here is the dummy code I used](http://pastebin.com/TpzNX3m6), I extracted pieces from your code. Note that I'm using dummy texture data, and I'm also using [GLAD](http://glad.dav1d.de/) instead of GLEW so simply switch that out if you want to keep GLEW. If you still can't resolve the problem, then I need to see your new code, and what you changed! :)

Comment: I have uploaded my new project to a github repo for ease of use at the link: https://github.com/Balajanovski/mandelbrot-fractal-drawer. Tell me if you are tired of helping though, I don't wanna become a help vampire :/

Comment: Just keep asking, that's what Stack Overflow and Gamedev is for! :) I took a quick glance at your code, the problem is that you call `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` before creating the `vbo` and `ebo`. If you take a look at the code I linked before, I set it up to create the `vao`, `vbo` and `ebo` and then it calls `glEnableVertexAttribArray`, etc.